# Navbar shrink effect implementation in Angular 7

Tags: bootstrap-4, angular7

I'm trying to migrate this bootstrap 4.2 template https://startbootstrap.com/template-overviews/new-age/ to Angular 7. Everything works fine except the "navbar-shrink effect". It's basically when you scroll down the page, the navbar changes its color to white with some kind of effect. The script doing that is located at https://blackrockdigital.github.io/startbootstrap-new-age/js/new-age.js.

[image: angular.json]

I tried adding that script to my `angular.json` file, but the Console log returned the following error `TypeError: $(...).offset(...) is undefined[Learn More] new-age.js:31`

[image: Problem]

In the picture above, you can see that I scrolled down the page, but the navbar didn't "shrink" like in that template, even with the scripts added.

[image: Working example]

And here, you can see it working in that template.

I've seen this kind of effect on many templates e.g. https://demos.creative-tim.com/now-ui-kit/index.html.

So my question is how do I achieve this in Angular?